# White line appears at the bottom of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I just published a very simple app on the App Store. I wrote it for iOS 9.1 because to download Xcode 8 I would have to upgrade my laptop to El Capitan or Sierra (it's running Yosemite slowly so I don't think its a good idea).

When I was testing the app, I used a device running iOS 9.1, because the iPhone used must be running the same OS number that the app was programmed for, for some reason.

I published the app and I downloaded into two phones, an iPhone 5s running iOS 9.3 and an iPhone SE running iOS 10. The 5s works fine, however when I run the app on the SE, thick white lines appear at the bottom of every UIButton. I've tried deleting the app and reinstalling, but the problem still occurs.

I've never coded on Swift 3, and this is my first App Store release, so I'm clueless as to what the problem is. I haven't found any information online regarding this.

Is this a problem I can fix? If so, how can I fix it?

Here's my app, btw (shameless plug) : https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/breakitup/id1207626557?l=ca&mt=8
[image: my app]
As you can see, white lines appear at the bottom of the buttons

Comment: I think we need screenshots and code to be able to help.

Comment: Nice designed app. Can you share a screenshot of the issue? My knee jerk reaction is its a layout issue. Maybe a lack of constraints.

Comment: @mrabins I have added a screenshot. I actually programatically added most of the buttons in, and the ones I did on storyboard have the same issue. If it is a layout issue, is there a reason it would be different in iOS 10 than 9?

Comment: It's a layout issue. No reason for OS differences. But the devices resolution is different. Hence the issue.

Comment: @mrabins I'm pretty sure the SE and 5s have the same resolution? http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/136692-apple-iphone-se-vs-iphone-5s-vs-iphone-5c-what-s-the-difference

Comment: Sorry I thought you said 5c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an issue with your code or XIB related issue.
Check your Setting -> General -> Accessibility -> Turn Off Button Shapes.
Run your project again. It will not shows you underline below buttons.